# Extracting string after pattern

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a series of url

```
www.domain.com/calendar.php?month=may.2019
www.domain.com/calendar.php?month=april.2019
www.domain.com/calendar.php?month=march.2019
www.domain.com/calendar.php?month=feb.2019
...
...
...
www.domain.com/calendar.php?month=feb.2007
```

I wanted to extract the year after month.

What I'm looking for

```
2019
2019
...
...
2007
```

and save them into another columns

Here's what I have:

```
data["urls"].str.extract('(?<=month=).*$')
```

Comment: Check with str.split

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Fix your code

```
df["urls"].str.extract('(?<=month=).*\.(\d{4})$')
```

---

If you can trust that all do have the same pattern, then these should work.

#### `split`

```
df["urls"].str.rsplit('.', 1).str[-1]
```

---

#### slice

```
df["urls"].str[-4:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, we can also use simple expression without look-arounds, such as:

```
.+month=.+\.([0-9]{4})
```

or:

```
month=.+\.([0-9]{4})
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/sANPX5/1/)

or:

```
.+month=.+\.(.+)
```

or:

```
month=.+\.(.+)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/6iYsPR/1)